# Freez static column in P-table

Tags: primeng, angular2-template, primeng-datatable, primeng-turbotable

I have a table with static actions column in first position remaining dynamic columns,
How to freeze only first actions column
[image: sample image here]

For example here Name is static column and remaining are dynamic then how to freeze name column only

Answer (score 0):

You could define frozen and scrollable columns as below

```
    this.scrollableCols = [
        { field: 'year', header: 'Year' },
        { field: 'brand', header: 'Brand' },
        { field: 'color', header: 'Color' },
        { field: 'year', header: 'Year' },
        { field: 'brand', header: 'Brand' },
        { field: 'color', header: 'Color' }
    ];

    this.frozenCols = [
        { field: 'vin', header: 'Vin' },
    ];
```

Your html would like below.

```
<p-table [columns]="scrollableCols" [frozenColumns]="frozenCols" [value]="cars" [scrollable]="true" scrollHeight="200px" frozenWidth="200px">
 <ng-template pTemplate="colgroup" let-columns>
 <colgroup>
   <col *ngFor="let col of columns" style="width:200px">
 </colgroup>
 </ng-template>
 <ng-template pTemplate="header" let-columns>
 <tr>
   <th *ngFor="let col of columns">
     {{col.header}}
   </th>
 </tr>
 </ng-template>
 <ng-template pTemplate="body" let-rowData let-columns="columns">
 <tr>
   <td *ngFor="let col of columns">
     {{rowData[col.field]}}
   </td>
 </tr>
 </ng-template>
</p-table>
```

Stackblitz link - https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-primeng-frozen-columns-nytg8b?file=src/app/table-scroll-demo.component.html

Comment: I know above approach but my first column is static one not included in the columns array